# E.g i open notepad and save it will open savedilog box and when i click on save ,i need to handle that event?

Tags: c#, windows

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

We can easily handle the form saveFileDialog1_FileOk Event.
How to handle "sytem" saveFileDialog_FileOk event ?

Comment: your question is not really clear. What exactly do you mean by:  handle "system" ?

Comment: This kind of action can be intercepted using WinAPI

Comment: From my system i save file from anywhere and click on save button handle event .

Comment: You may be able to do this via [UI Automation Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748252(v=vs.110).aspx) but it would be up to *you* to determine how you would "identify" save dialogs - especially if you want to handle custom save file dialogs in other applications.

Comment: You are asking about your solution, not your problem. What are you really trying to achieve? Please be specific in your problem statement.